# How to access a specific range of bits in a string

Tags: c, string, byte

So for example lets say I have:

```
uint8_t version = 1;
uint16_t type = 1;
uint32_t program = 0;
```

and I convert version, type, and program into a string, and lets say I store them all in:

```
char *string;
```

How do I access the first 8 bits of string to get the version variable, and then convert it back into an integer? Then the next 16 bits for type, and convert it to an int, and then access the next 32 bits (4 bytes) of program and convert it to an int.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `void` pointer:

```
void *ptr = str;
uint8_t version = *(uint8_t*)ptr;
ptr = *(uint8_t*)ptr + 1;
uint16_t type = *(uint16_t*)ptr;
ptr = *(uint16_t*)ptr + 1;
uint16_t program = *(uint16_t*)ptr;
ptr = *(uint16_t*)ptr + 1;
```

Writing this variables to `char* string` you can perform in the same way (using void pointer).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
struct {
    uint8_t version;
    uint16_t type;
    uint32_t program;
} header;
memcpy(&header, data, sizeof(header));
```

This assumes that `data` has been produced by copying the data from a `struct` identical to `header` into an array of characters. If you need interoperability with other types of hardware, use functions from the [`htonl/ntohl`](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/htonsman.html) group to do the conversion. The sender calls the `htonl` to convert to network order, and the receiver calls the `ntohl` to convert to its hardware-specific order.

Comment: Also, be careful about endianness. You'll want to choose whether you use little or big endian numbers, and stick with that.

Comment: @RyanPendleton My assumption is that the entire action happens on a single computer. If OP plans for interoperability across multiple systems, he would need a different approach.

Comment: we are told to put all of this into network byte order. Yes, we are communicating across multiple machines. We are to do a multicast operation.